# What is the accepted portlet framework for .Net?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, portlet

What is the accepted "portlet" framework for .Net these days?  By this, I mean the whole "add little widgets to a page and move them around" type of thing.

I know that Web Parts were big at one time, but is this architecture still the "accepted" method in the .Net world?  Is this still what Sharepoint uses?  (And should that matter?)

I need to use portlet-type things for a client project, and I don't want to re-invent the wheel.  I'd like to use the tool that have the most momentum and community support behind it?

Comment: "accepted" is a sort of hard term use but yes sharepoint is the portlet style platform de jour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint still uses web parts. That being said, there are many ways of creating SharePoint web parts.

You can't really go wrong with ASP.NET User Controls. User Controls give you a lot of freedom, are still very "accepted" and supported (and that won't stop anytime soon). What's more, you will be able to re-use the control everywhere (SharePoint or not) with little refactoring which is a big plus in my book.

You can read this article by Scott Gu for more details : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/02/Writing-Custom-Web-Parts-for-SharePoint-2007.aspx

Comment: And note that the story is even better now with Visual Studio 2010.